# Issue with load Static Resource to Aura component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, aura, static-resources

I have a folder that I compressed to ZIP and I want to import it to my aura component, but the "afterScriptLoaded" is never call.

```
<aura:component  implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader" access="global">
     <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.ckeditor + '/ckeditor.js'}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterLoad}" />
</aura:component>
```

I also tried :

```
<ltng:require scripts="/resource/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"
          afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterLoad}" />
```

JS- Controller:

```
({
    afterLoad: function(component, event, helper) {

        console.log("Done Loaded script");

    }
})
```

In vf page This line working as expected: (Loading the same file)

```
  <apex:includescript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.ckeditor, 'ckeditor.js')}" />
```

Any help with this?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Hi @CommonCoreTawan, unfortunately, I didn't.
I created a VF page and used it in Iframe inside my component.
If you'll find any solution I will be more than happy to hear.
Thanks.